# agda - type of expression with mutual Lists not found

Tags: agda

In Agda 2.5.1.1 on Windows, after the code below is loaded (it corresponds to the tutorial https://github.com/k0001/tut-agda/blob/master/SetsParametric.agda), the C-c C-d type-checking does find the type `List₁ _A_2 _B_3` for the `[]` expression, but no reasonable type for any more structured expression like `true ∷ []` , just underscore and number is returned, like `_5` . Any ideas what the reason could be, please?

The previous exercises of the tutorial work well.

```
 module Sets.Parametric where

 open import Sets.Enumerated using (Bool; true; false; ⊤; tt)

 data List₁ (A B : Set) : Set
 data List₂ (A B : Set) : Set
 data List₁ (A B : Set) where
  []  :                 List₁ A B
  _∷_ : A → List₂ A B → List₁ A B

data List₂ (A B : Set) where
  _∷_ : B → List₁ A B → List₂ A B
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-overloaded constructors are inferrable and hence the type of `[]` is inferred, but overloaded constructors are only checkable, so you can't infer the type `true ∷ []` — only check it against `List₂ Bool A`.

Otherwise type-directed resolution for overloaded constructors would be too complicated. E.g. the type of the second argument of `_∷_` could depend on its first argument, then figuring out whether `_∷_` belongs to `List₁` or `List₂` would require solving two possibly non-trivial unification problems (one for `List₁` and one for `List₂`) which likely will be postponed and sit in memory until it's clear which `_∷_` the user means. Agda already generates lots of metavariables and I don't see any reason to increase this number and complicate type checking to incorporate this not super useful feature.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. One more thing - I cannot find how the check of an expression against a given type can be performed. _C-c C-d_ is not usable here, I guess.

Comment: @veeco, the best option, I think, is just to write `test : A; test = x` in the buffer with code. There are other options like using reflection (which is an overkill for such a simple task) or defining (or importing from the `Function` module) `_∋_ : ∀ {α} -> (A : Set α) -> A -> A; A ∋ x = x` and then evaluating `C-c C-n A ∋ x`, but this way it's not always clear that the value indeed type checks against the type successfully, because there can be sneaking metavariables. With recent versions of Agda you can write `_ : A; _ = x` if you only want to perform a check and not to bind a name.

Comment: Thanks, I used the easiest variant from your advice: added `test : List₁ Bool ⊤; test = true ∷ (tt ∷ [])` to the code and the command _C-c C-d test_ gave the expected answer.